# Can Windows VSS create a snapshot for units smaller than a single volume

Tags: windows, vss

Can Windows Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) create a snapshot for units smaller than a single volume (that is, a set of files and directories)?

If yes, how can one see (prefferably via UI) for each snapshot of a given volume which files/directories it includes?

Comment: Do you ask on how to program a VSS backup, or to use shadow copy in windows ? this is really not the same topic.

Comment: I'm not asking how to program VSS

Comment: When you enable shadow copie, it use a % up to the reserve you define. You can see file version in explorer over folder that shadow copie is enabled

Comment: @Ivan VSS stands for "Volume Shadow-Copy Service", so I'd say no, you can't take smaller snapshots. If you're looking for backup options, there are many other (free or commercial) utilities that would do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Windows VSS currently works only for a full NTFS filesystem.
So no possibility to do a snapshot for a set of directories or files.

An option is to make a separate NTFS partition for the desired directories, then [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) this partition inside the original filesystem. You can then snapshot only this new separate partition. But this is not really handy.